# React Native App: Time Format Conversion: From as (2018-10-09T06:20:33.628Z) to Epoch timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, react-native

> Hello all.
>
> I have the time format from firebase. Show me how to convert to Epoch
>   timestamp on my real device.

I have the code below and work with the Genymotion emulator while debugging, when debugging is turned off it returns NaN.

```
    /**
     * parseDate
     * @param {*} dateString 
     */
    static parseDate(dateString){
        var time = Date.parse(dateString);
        if(!time){
            time = Date.parse(dateString.replace("T"," "));
            if(!time){
                bound = dateString.indexOf('T');
                var dateData = dateString.slice(0, bound).split('-');
                var timeData = dateString.slice(bound+1, -1).split(':');

                time = Date.UTC(dateData[0],dateData[1]-1,dateData[2],timeData[0],timeData[1],timeData[2]);
            }
        }
        return time / 1000; // -> 1539068005
    }
```

> Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please use package **[react-moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment)** by installing

```
npm install react-moment
```

Import the package

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
```

Use by

```
<Moment format="DD MMM YYYY" element={Text}>{new Date(dateString)}</Moment>
```

for date-time format review the [moment docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)